# Oracle view with ML tables I want optimizer to use one ML table only

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, multilingual

Oracle 11g. I have ML (multilingual) child tables for text, one child table per parent/language. So for a parent table PRODUCT, I have PRODUCT_EN, PRODUCT_FR etc. I want to have a single view that combines all ML tables. When I query this for a specific language I'd like Oracle optimizer (Join Elimination?) to be smart enough to only access the ML table required. So if I specify lan_id (language id) = 5 (French) it should ignore the English and other other translation tables.
Here's a couple of views that return the correct data, but from the plan I see a query against French still access English:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myproduct_ml AS
SELECT p.PROD_ID, STATUS, 
       ml.lan_id, ml.prod_name
FROM myproduct p JOIN
(SELECT en.* FROM myproduct_en en WHERE lan_id = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT fr.* FROM myproduct_fr fr WHERE lan_id = 5) ml
 ON (p.prod_id = ml.prod_id);

 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myproduct_ml AS
SELECT p.PROD_ID, STATUS, 
       ml.lan_id, ml.prod_name
FROM myproduct p JOIN myproduct_en ml ON (p.prod_id = ml.prod_id) WHERE lan_id = 1
 UNION ALL
SELECT p.PROD_ID, STATUS, 
       ml.lan_id, ml.prod_name
FROM myproduct p JOIN myproduct_fr ml ON (p.prod_id = ml.prod_id) WHERE lan_id = 5;

 select * from myproduct_ml WHERE lan_id = 5 ;
```

lan_id doesn't need to be in the ML table, as the suffix specifies the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a separate table for each language anyway? That would mean to have to add a table everytime you introduce a new language and have to change all queries. That must not be. Added data should lead to added rows only so that the queries continue working.

So make this one language table instead and you are done.

Comment: I have a single table at the moment. But I'm designing for speed over development. The tables can be generated anyway. But having an ML table per parent table/language, I partition (I don't have a licence for the Oracle facility) the data as much as possible, so queries access the smallest data set.

Comment: Very bad idea. This won't speed anything up. As you see you would suddenly have to deal with multiple tables in a query rather than one, which naturally slows things down. And your idea that the optimizer might see through this and only read one table doesn't work. So you would have to write all your queries dynamically to avoid that. Don't do that. Make sure to have a proper index on the unique key `prod_id` + `lan_id`. (I'd even write two, one on `(prod_id, lan_id)` and one on (lan_id, prod_id)` and see which one gets used.) That should be fast enough.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I was hoping there was a way to give the optimizer enough clues. I'll probably have to make do with one table. But in one case I have over half a million rows per language, and want to support 40 languages, so 20 million rows. There a text index on the ML column, and I support Chinese, Japanese, Korean as well as European, so thinking about different lexars, though I know I can use MULTI_LEXAR. I could have one table, but a column per language. More impact on the application, which needs to append _FR instead of LAN_ID = 5.

Comment: Well, usually you'd operate on a set of products, e.g. all products of one order or of one supplier. So from 500,000 products you'd access, say, 500. Using an index on these should get you the language entries quickly. Have you encountered severe performance issues already? Maybe you are struggling with a problem that doesn't really exist.

Comment: I prototyped both approaches using 10000 rows * 15 languages.A select using PKs is 3x faster using _ml suffix field, as you'd expect.

Comment: A search with no index (why?) is vastly (0.7 vs 10s) faster with _ml suffix fields. With a CONTEXT text index on the text fields, _ml suffix is four times faster . But with a CTXCAT text index carrying lan_id as an additional index, the difference is _ml is two times faster. So _ml columns are faster. However there's more maintenance/coding overhead, and not as space efficient if many records are not translated.